# How to validate bootstrap modal using PHP codes?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to validate every data that the user input in modal. The problem is not working at all, even I put the "required" in the text input same problem. It accept empty string. I don't want to accept empty string and the maximum length that user can input 45. I used bootstrap to create a modal and PHP for server side

```
<?php require_once('../../private/initialize.php'); ?>
<?php
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
        $validation = new Validation();
        $data = [
            "category_description" => $_POST['category_description']
        ];

        $validation->validate($data, [
            "category_description" => "required|maxlen:45"
        ]);
        $errors = $validation->getErrors();

    } else {
        $data = [
           "category_description" => ""         
        ];
        $errors = [
            "category_description" => ""
        ];
    }

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if($data) {
            echo $data;
        }


<div class="modal" id="myModal1" > <!-- start update modal -->
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content " style="height:auto">

                    <!-- Modal Header -->
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <h4 class="modal-title">Update Category</h4>
                      <button @click="clearData" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fas fa-times"></i></button>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Modal body -->
                    <form method="post" action="unit_category/index.php">
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="category_id" name="category_id" v-model="category_id" disabled>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <input type="text" id="category_description" name="category_description" v-model="category_description" value="<?php echo $data['category_description'] ?>" placeholder="Enter Description" class="form-control <?php if(!empty($errors['category_description'])) { echo 'is-invalid'; } ?>" required>
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback"><?php echo $errors['category_description'] ?></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- Modal footer -->
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                          <button type="submit" @click="updateCategory" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Update Category</button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- end update modal -->
```

Comment: You need to share actual code ideally. That photo doesn't help much. Specifically what are you trying to do, what is the expected result, what is happening instead?

Comment: I want to put validation on modal. Don't accept empty string and the maximum length must be 45

Comment: hey guy, look this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation